# Is there a good way to ensure that I can still log into a machine even under heavy load?

Tags: ssh, nice, cgroup

I am considering increasing the priority of sshd by setting minimum niceness -20 via a nice stanza in the upstart script.

Has anyone done this? Does it work? Has anyone done this and had problems?
Has anyone set up a cgroup for sshd and tested under heavy load?

Comment: I think any answers you get will have more opinion than fact.

Comment: I'm seeking opinions of people with more experience than myself. So long as the opinions are backed up with specific reasoning I'm open to them ;- )

Comment: The problem is that this site is not. We even have a specific close reason for it: `primarily opinion-based
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.`

Comment: IMO, what you should ask is something along the lines of "what can I do to login under heavy load" or something.